# PHP link in search results not working correct

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a little problem, I have been testing numbers of variants but I don´t get it to work.
I have a link in the search result.. (Full text search working)

```
> while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
> 
> $id = $row['id'];
> 
> echo '<a href=profile1.php?id= . $row["id"] . >.INFO.</a>';
```

It shows INFO as a link and when i click on it, i jump to profile1.php but I´m not seeing any results, it is totaly blank page. the url I get is .../profile1.php?id=

Here is my profile.php

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", ""); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$id=$_GET["id"];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, brand FROM table WHERE id=?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("d", $id); /* BIND DATA TO QUERY */

    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

    $stmt->bind_result($name, $brand); /* BIND RESULT TO VARIABLE */

    $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH DATA */

    printf("%s - %s", $name, $brand); /* ECHO DATA */

    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE STATEMENT */
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I hope someone can help me.. Thanks!!!

Comment: You're using the code I have given. Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

Do this .

```
 echo "<a href=profile1.php?id=$row[id]>INFO</a>";
```

or this.

```
echo '<a href=profile1.php?id='.$row['id'].'>INFO</a>'
```

Answer (score -1):

### Note:

- You assigned your id to a variable, so better use that variable to the link. You should learn how to incorporate variables to your link.
- Better use a single tick (`'`) when using a variable inside. It's okay not to use single tick (`'`) in your query **IF** the variable you are binding is an integer type.

Your link should look like this:

```
 $id = $row['id'];

 echo '<a href="profile1.php?id='.$id.'" >.INFO.</a>';
```

And your *select query* should look like this (`profile1.php`):

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$_GET["id"]."'";
```

It is also recommendable to use `mysqli_*` rather than the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API. Read here to learn more about [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

If you had it into `mysqli_*` prepared statement, it would look like this (`profile1.php`):

```
<?php

  /* RE-ESTABLISH YOUR MYSQL CONNECTION */
  $con = new mysqli("YourHost", "yourUsername", "YourPassword", "YourDB"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

  /* CHECK CONNECTION */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT name, brand FROM table WHERE id = ?")){
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET["id"]); /* PARAMETIZE GET ID TO QUERY */  
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */    
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $brand); /* BIND RESULT TO VARIABLE */
    $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH DATA */
    printf("%s - %s", $name, $brand); /* ECHO DATA */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE STATEMENT */
  }

  $con->close();

?>
```